# how to get input and puting it through functions within a program?

Tags: python

```
    def makeArray(a):
        a = []
        for i in range(n):
            a.append(i)
        return a

    print makeArray(a)

    import random
    def shuffleArray(a):

    size = len(a)

    for i in range(size):
        r = random.randrange(0,size)
        if r != i:
            temp = a[r]
            a[r] = a[i]
            a[i] = temp
    return a

print shuffleArray(makeArray(a))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = raw_input("please enter size of array: ")
    print ("you entered " + a)

    makeArray(a)
    shuffleArray(a)
```

how do I make this piece of code ask for input via terminal and take that input through both of the functions then returning a result? I'm asking the user for input storing that input in a variable printing the result and then shuffling by randominzing.

Comment: What is your question? You seem to have the right code. Is it not working or something?

Answer (score 1):

```
def makeArray(n):
    a = []      #you were using 'a' for the size and the array itself at the same time
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(i)
    return a        

import random

def shuffleArray(a):
    size = len (a)
    for i in range(size):
        r = random.randrange(0,size)
        if r != i:
            temp = a[r]
            a[r] = a[i]
            a[i] = temp
    return a



if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input("please enter size of array: "))      #'n' needs to be an integer because it's the size of the array
    print ("you entered " + str(n))

    anArray = makeArray(n)        
    print shuffleArray(anArray)
```

you can also replace:

```
def makeArray(n):
    a = []
    for i in range(n):
        a.append(i)
    return a
```

with:

```
def makeArray(n):
    a = list(range(n))
    return a
```